# How do I left align title text in title bar using Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Can anyone show how I can set the alignment of the title in a title bar to left justified.
I'm currently trying this but it isn't working:

```
var p = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        title: 'my title',
        style: {
            'text-align':'left'
        }
    }   
    ]
}); 
Ext.Viewport.add(p);
```

**2nd attempt:**
Not now able to have the title left and the toolbar button right!

```
var p = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        layout: {
            pack: 'end'
        },
        title: {
            title: 'mytitle',
            style: {
                'text-align':'left'
            }
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'mybutton',
                align: 'right'
            }
        ]
    }   
    ]
}); 
Ext.Viewport.add(p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add style to the toolbar but not to the title element. Do this:

```
xtype: 'toolbar',
docked: 'top',
title: {
    title: 'my title',
    style: {
        'text-align':'left'
    }
}
```

Look this http://jsfiddle.net/xv67e/

Comment: shouldn't the `text-align` style on the toolbox place the title left if it were so?

Comment: @Tikkes: Why it shuld do it? text-align works with inline element but not the block

Comment: @Tikkes: Please see my 2nd edit above. I'm now not able to align the button in the other direction...

Comment: @Tikkes: I don't think that this is the problem. It depends on what result you want to get.

Comment: I'm kind of oblivious as to why your answer isn't working. It should be the right way to do it.

Comment: That's what I was after. I had to add a slight margin to the button which I don't normally have to do.  Any reason why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just `align` and not `text-align`, put it outside of the `style` block, right under `title`.

More info on [this page](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.1/demos/Ext.picker.Slot.align/viewer.html)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. I have one button packed to the end (right). But on an iPhone the central title bleeds into the button. Hence the reason for wanting the title to be left justified. Any other ideas?

Comment: hmm uhm you could also try the `layout` block. Like this: layout: {
    pack: 'justify', align: 'left'
}

Comment: @Tikkes: You can't change layout of tollbar, because it has docked top. It means that all inner items will be paste to the body and fill all horizontal space.(-webkit-box-flex: 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can give items of a Ext.TitleBar an **align** configuration of left or right which will dock them to the left or right of the bar.